# Delete a lot of files and sub folders with c# and threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Does anybody have a sample or no how to delete a lot of files and sub directories in a folder with threads and c# .net.

Thanks

Comment: This is typically a bad idea. Disk operations on physical disks tend to slow down when you do more of them in parallel. You can create a `BackgroundWorker` if you want to keep your UI responsive, but more threads won't speed things up in this case.

Comment: are you intend to delete directory completely or just specific files?

Comment: The entire directory and all the files/folders in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to call `Directory.Delete(directory, true);` That will delete the directory, all of the subdirectories, and all files. No threading required.

If you want to do it asynchronously (i.e. have your program do other things while the directory deletion is happening), then take a look at [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Do [something like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    try
    {
         Directory.Delete(path, true);
    }
    catch { } //Do something 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave it upon the operating system. It knows far better how to schedule the operations to make it really fast and well performing even under heady workload. In case the rest of your program can't be blocked, just dispatch it from a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to try multithreading it (I imagine that there might cases like trying to get at an unavailable network resource where a thread pool will speed up the overall time):

```
List<Task> tasks =
(from c in yourDirList select new Action(() =>
 {
  try
  {
   // do it
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   // log it
  }
 })
 into action
 select Task.Factory.StartNew(action)).ToList();

tasks.ForEach(c => c.Wait());
```

Comment: This is harder than it looks because things have to be done in a particular order: all files and directories within a directory must be removed before the directory can be removed. Since the directory structure is arbitrarily deep, you end up having to include logic that makes the directory deletion wait until all of the child elements are deleted.